# how to make a function return a structure pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I want to make the function return the address of a particular node .but the compiler is 
not detecting the node datatype structure i created.

```
struct node
{
int data;

node *link;
};

node *header,*current;
node traverse(int pos);


node *Linkedlist::traverse(int pos)
{
    int location = 0;  
    current->link = header->link;
    node *address = new node;
    address->data = NULL;
    address->link = NULL;


    while(current->link != NULL)
    {

        if(location == pos)
        {
            cout <<current->link->data <<" "<< endl; 
            address->link=current->link;
        }
        location ++;
        current->link = current->link->link;

    }


    return  address->link;
}
```

Comment: Since this is a C++ question, consider `std::unique_ptr` and/or `std::shared_ptr`. If you find yourself writing `new` and `delete` often then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I did not understand anything from your question. Please, be more concise about what you are asking. 
Also, your code seems to have too much faults and bad practices.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
return  *address;
```

to

```
return  address;
```

Answer (score 1):

As address is a pointer variable to node, you need to simply return the variable.

A `*` preceding a pointer variable is an explicit referencing, which means to get the value pointed by the pointer variable `address`. This is antagonistic to what the operator `&` would have done, fetch the address of a variable.

```
return  address;
```

So its logical that you should return the variable instead of returning the value pointed by the variable.

Note, care needs to be taken by the caller of `traverse` to free the memory explicitly by calling `delete` else this would result in memory leak. This is because of a potential design issue, where you have allocated a heap object inside a local  scope and returned the address.

```
node * foo = Linkedlist::traverse(n);
...............
delete foo;
```

You could have simply created the object in the heap or add it as a class member, where in the former case, you can easily transfer the ownership of the object from one scope to another, where in the second case, the lifetime of the object would have been controlled by the object `Linkedlist`